# ORA-01407: cannot update ("SYSADM"."PS_LM_ENRLMT"."LM_ACT_ID") to NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello Everyone,

I am getting this error when I am trying to run the below query.

```
Update PS_LM_ENRLMT A
Set A.LM_ACT_ID = (Select B.LM_ACT_ID FROM PS_LM_ACT B                                                                                 
               where B.LM_ACT_ID = A.LM_ACT_ID                     
               And B.LM_ROW_ADDED_DTTM < '09-DEC-13 05.35.35.000000 PM'        
               AND A.LM_ACT_ID = 1166            
               And A.LM_CI_ID!= 1196)
```

To avoid the Null error I updated the query as below:

```
Update PS_LM_ENRLMT A                                

Set A.LM_ACT_ID = (Select B.LM_ACT_ID FROM PS_LM_ACT B       
               where B.LM_ACT_ID = A.LM_ACT_ID        
               And B.LM_ROW_ADDED_DTTM < '09-DEC-13 05.35.35.000000 PM'          
               AND A.LM_ACT_ID = 1166           
               And A.LM_CI_ID!= 1196)           
where exists      
(Select B.LM_ACT_ID FROM PS_LM_ACT B                              
               where B.LM_ACT_ID = A.LM_ACT_ID         
               And B.LM_ROW_ADDED_DTTM < '09-DEC-13 05.35.35.000000 PM'          
               AND A.LM_ACT_ID = 1166          
               And A.LM_CI_ID!= 1196)
```

The query runs successfully but no data is getting updated. I am not able to find the reason. Can anyone please help.

Thanks,
AJ

Comment: Your subquery is not returning rows.  I'd start there

Comment: How is `PS_LM_ENRLMT` created? I guess the column `A.LM_ACT_ID` can't be null ... note: your first statement would change all values in the table; the second one either all or none

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is no row in the main table for which the subquery returns a result.  Therefore your first statement tried to update all rows to NULL, presumably violating a constraint on the table; and your second statement did not update any rows because all were filtered out by the EXISTS condition.

Basically, you need to look at the data and the query and figure out why this is the case.  However, there is one obvious potential problem in your query:

```
And B.LM_ROW_ADDED_DTTM < '09-DEC-13 05.35.35.000000 PM'
```

This looks like you are comparing a DATE or TIMESTAMP column to a string, which means that the column value will be implicitly converted to a string, using the NLS_DATE_FORMAT for the session, in order to do the comparison.  If the NLS_DATE_FORMAT doesn't match up with the format you used for the string, the results will be rather unpredictable.  In this case, even if the format used is what you expect, I doubt the results will be what you want, since comparing strings in that format won't produce the same results as comparing the equivalent dates.  (E.G. "08-DEC-14" is lexically less than "09-DEC-13" although it represents a date almost a year later.

It would be better to use a date or timestamp literal, so no type conversion takes place:

```
And B.LM_ROW_ADDED_DTTM < TIMESTAMP '2013-13-09 17:35:35.000'
```

(And if that column is actually a string, in the desired format, then it's still true that a comparison of the strings is not the same as a comparison of the equivalent date values.)

**Edited to add**
Looked a little closer and the update makes no sense at all.  The subquery requires that `B.LM_ACT_ID = A.LM_ACT_ID`, and then if a row is found you are updating A.LM_ACT_ID to the value from B.LM_ACT_ID - which by definition is the same value.  So if this did update any rows, it would just be setting them to the same value they already have.  Looks like you need to reevaluate what it is you are trying to do.